# Regex Match PHP Comment

Tags: php, regex, comments

Ive been trying to match PHP comments using regex.

```
//([^<]+)\r\n
```

Thats what ive got but it doesn't really work.

Ive also tried

```
//([^<]+)\r
//([^<]+)\n
//([^<]+)
```

...to no avail

Comment: Could do with a little more information about what you're trying to achieve, what language you're matching this *from*.

Answer (score 1):

In what program are you coding this regex?  Your final example is a good sanity check if you're worried that the newline chars aren't working.  (I have no idea why you don't allow less-than in your comment; I'm assuming that's specific to your application.)

Try

```
//[^<]+
```

and see if that works.  As Draemon says, you might have to escape the diagonals.  You might also have to escape the parentheses.  I can't tell if you know this, but parentheses are often used to enclose *capturing groups*.  Finally, check whether there is indeed at least one character after the double slashes.

Answer (score 1):

To match comments, you have to think there are two types of comments in PHP 5 :

- comments which start by `//` and go to the end of the line
- comments that start by `/*` and go to `*/`

Considering you have these two lines first :

```
$filePath = '/home/squale/developpement/astralblog/website/library/HTMLPurifier.php';
$str = file_get_contents($filePath);
```

You could match the first ones with :

```
$matches_slashslash = array();
if (preg_match_all('#//(.*)$#m', $str, $matches_slashslash)) {
    var_dump($matches_slashslash[1]);
}
```

And the second ones with :

```
$matches_slashstar = array();
if (preg_match_all('#/\*(.*?)\*/#sm', $str, $matches_slashstar)) {
    var_dump($matches_slashstar[1]);
}
```

But you will probably get into troubles with '`//`' in the middle of string `(what about heredoc syntax, btw, did you think about that one ? )`, or "toggle comments" like this :

```
/*
echo 'a';
/*/
echo 'b';
//*/
```

*(Just add a slash at the begining to "toggle" the two blocks, if you don't know the trick)*

So... Quite hard to detect comments with only regex...

---

Another way would be to use the **PHP Tokenizer**, which, obviously, knows how to parse PHP code and comments.

For references, see :

- [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)
- [`List of Parser Tokens`](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

With that, you would have to use the tokenizer on your string of PHP code, iterate on all the tokens you get as a result, and detect which ones are comments.

Something like this would probably do :

```
$tokens = token_get_all($str);

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token[0] == T_COMMENT
        || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
        // This is a comment ;-)
        var_dump($token);
    }
}
```

And, as output, you'll get a list of stuff like this :

```
array
  0 => int 366
  1 => string '/** Version of HTML Purifier */' (length=31)
  2 => int 57
```

or this :

```
array
  0 => int 365
  1 => string '// :TODO: make the config merge in, instead of replace
' (length=55)
  2 => int 117
```

*(You "just" might to strip the `//` and `/* */`, but that's up to you ; at least, you have extracted the comments ^^ )*

If you really want to detect comments without any kind of strange error due to "strange" syntax, I suppose this would be the way to go ;-)

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is not meaningful if the regex pattern does not contain a start or end of string anchor (such as `^` or `$`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the "//":

```
\/\/([^<]+)
```

Comment: It only matches one comment though. It wont find them all within the document

Comment: You didn't ask for that. But it doesn't make any sense. Regexes only apply to a *line* (generally speaking). If you pass every line through this regex then it may do what you want. What are you actually trying to do though?

Answer (score 0):

This will match comments in PHP (both /* */ and // format)

```
/(\/\*).*?(\*\/)|(\/\/).*?(\n)/s
```

To get all matches, use preg_match_all to get array of matches.